# How can I get my build script run phases to run when performing an Archive operation in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode

I basically set my build numbers to be the count of Git commits by setting up two build phases that run specific scripts — just like in this question:

[Why won't my build phase scripts be executed when creating an IPA from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082692/why-wont-my-build-phase-scripts-be-executed-when-creating-an-ipa-from-command-l)

However, I found that when I `Archive` either with Xcode or with the fastlane toolchain, the scripts are **not** invoked.

Why is that? I would have assumed that build gets run when you do an archive.  How can I make these build phases run even for the Archive action?

Comment: Run script build phases will run during Archiving always and during building if you have not checked the `Run script only when installing` option. Can you try adding another build phase with this script and see if the notification gets displayed? `osascript -e 'display notification "Building complete"'`

Answer (score 15):

Have you try to open your scheme using `Edit scheme...`, then expand the `Archive` Action and add a `Post Action` ?

[image]

Comment: this however doesnt stop the archiving process if exit code is 1 and doesnt output a log either

Comment: @Return-1that wasn't the question was it?

Comment: no but it's a good pitfall to be aware of. It's an XCode shortcoming that hasn't been fixed in years and that people are complaining about due to it being peculiar. The comment isn't aimed in devaluing the answer, its a warning about XCode being unreasonable.